# How to fix bad shading on cylinder with a difference boolean?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I've booleaned a simple cylinder with 32 vertices and I am wondering how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: check this guy, he has plenty of tutorials for that... https://www.youtube.com/c/JoshGambrell

Comment: if lmg1114's answer doesn't satisfy you please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Auto Smooth* as recommended by lmg1114, or use this kind of topology (I'm not sure about all your vertical edge loops):

[image]

Comment: I have a hard time recreating the topology as shown on the screenshot as I am new to Blender.

Comment: use the knife tool, K to activate, C to cut perpendicularly to the view, Z to cut through, E to keep activated...

Comment: Nevermind, I just managed to make it identical. Thanks for reply! :D

Answer (score 1):

'Auto Smooth' under the normals section of the Object Data Properties tab should do the trick for you. Oftentimes adjusting the angle of the Auto Smooth will also be necessary.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have already applied 60 degrees of smoothness.