# extra hidden faces?

Tags: modeling

As you can see I have the face select option active, and yet I have found that I have a lot of *edges with dots on them* and when I select the dot and press <kbd>X</kbd> and delete face then the dot goes away and nothing else gets affected.

The dots are not the issue. I realize that when I use the face select tool, then the dots will only appear in the center of every face to demonstrate that is a face. But there are somehow tiny faces that blender has found *that appear to be right on edges.*

So for some reason, I have a lot of very tiny basically nonexistent faces that were made, and I had no idea how. I am individually selecting them all and deleting them because I have found it has caused me issues when doing some stuff with that object.

So my question I ask is there an easier way to select all those very tiny faces and delete them all at once.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: From the menu at the top of the 3D viewport  (with your object selected in edit mode) try `Mesh > Clean Up > Delete Loose`.

Comment: When I did that, it just deleted 4 faces that were supposed to stay and it didn't even touch the ones I'm having issues with :(

Comment: Yeah, not sure then - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It's hard to tell without seeing more of your project. If you want to post a .blend file so the people here can have a look, you can do it here - https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1N98jVnD" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1N98jVnD/)

Comment: Something happened and many sections that I was nowhere around got deleted, so ill have to figure out how to fix that or ill just go back to my backup model. So ignore those areas. You'll see the area I'm talking about in the round sections that are supposed to be magnets.

Comment: Yeah. I see it. It looks like you have some messed up topology in that area. Inside the cube, if you look at the "outer" ring of the magnet, there are duplicate faces - there are some unattached edges too, but if I select them to delete, it takes stuff you want with it. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to get into the full details of it now, but I suggest a full re-work. I'll try to give it another look later when I have time, but hopefully before then, someone else can show you how to fix it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem there is a "quick and easy" to fix this one.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm sure it had something to do with the way I had to make the circle on the face. I started with the solid side then subdivided it by 10 ten subdivided it again by 1. Then I selected the faces I wanted the circle to be and used the loop tool to make the circle. And extruded the circle inside the cube. After I did the extrude I noticed the faces that connected with the circle didn't look flat. It had a gradient look, kinda like the way beveled edges look where one side is lighter and the other side is darker. So I selected those faces and used the inset face tool and pulled the.

Comment: So I selected those faces and used the inset face tool and pulled the handle away from the face, and that flattened the face. So I'm kinda thinking that had something to do with the extra tiny faces I'm finding.

Comment: Also, I think I know why those faces got deleted that were nowhere in the magnet. I set the viewing range to 1.5 m so when I select the dots to faces I wanted to delete without confusing it with all the dots on the other side of the cube. I think that just because I can't see it doesn't mean I still couldn't select it. So when I was selecting the faces around the magnet it also selected other dots on the opposite side of the cube without me knowing because I couldn't see that far, so ill have to start over or duplicate to one of the previous backups.

Comment: *"I have a lot of very tiny basically nonexistence faces"* - Do you mean the little dots in the screenshot? That's the center of the face. The dots are an overlay, visible in *Face Selection* mode. You can turn it on/off in the *Overlays* menu.

Comment: @blunder the dots are not the issue. I realize that when I use the face select tool, then the dots will only appear in the center of ever face to demonstrate that is a face. But there are somehow tiny faces that blender has found that appears to be right on edges. I hope that makes sense now, if not let me know. I did upload the blend file above, so you could look around the circles extruded on the cube and see the dots I'm talking about.

Comment: You mean the fact that faces centers (dots) that are right on an edge. Ok, I see... Yes, that's because you have duplicated vertices. Do a merge *By Distance* and the dots on the edges are gone. Enable *Auto Smooth* to fix the shading. But as *Christopher Bennett* already mentioned you have also *a lot* of flipped and overlapping faces. Turn on the *Face Orientation* overlay (red/blue) and check the inside of the box, especially the circles. There is some mess.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fk8Bxds is this the main cause of my issues. I've never seen this stuff before.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Turn on *Face Selection* mode with the dot overlay. You will notice that there are 2 faces, the small blue one, and a bigger, flipped, red one that overlaps it. Just select and hide/delete the big one and you will see what's going on. The faces are basically connected to the same edge and overlap. That's bad. You need to clean it up, delete the unwanted faces.

Comment: I tried looking up what dot overlay is, and I can't seem to figure out what that is still. I didn't know I could hide faces, I thought you could only hide a whole object. That's new, thanks for telling me that. I deleted the small blue ring from the previous image. And when I rotate to see the circle from the outside, the whole circle is red. I selected it and thought I could just rotate it 180, but then it really looked messed up. I didn't know about auto smoothing....

Comment: I think most of my problem was how when I saw the shading issue I used the inset face to fix that, it made those tiny faces I'm complaining about. https://ibb.co/album/ydR7Wf this is what I was dealing with (they are numbered in order) and in the end after I used the inset face to pull it out you could see it added those dots on the edge lines. So thank you for that for all this. I do have another issue if you think it can be solved. I might have to make all this over again, so I may have to go this way. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229051/permanently-joining-objects-forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a summary of the comments.

**1. Duplicated Vertices**

The first issue, the "hidden invisible tiny faces", which this question is about, are caused by duplicated vertices. If you active the face center overlay (*Center*), a little dot is shown for the center of each face. You can see them in *Edit* mode when you active *Face Selection* (<kbd>3</kbd>) mode.

The problem is shown by the fact that there are some face centers (dots) exactly in the middle on one edge, marked yellow in the screenshot. These faces have some width but a zero-length.

[image: screenshot with overlays]

The fix for this is easy. Select everything (<kbd>A</kbd>), and press <kbd>M</kbd>, and choose *Merge By Distance*. Additionally, you need to enable [Auto Smooth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/206167/107598) to get a clean shading.

**2. Holes In the Mesh**

If you have activated the *Face Orientation* and switch view mode (<kbd>Z</kbd>) to *Solid*, you will see there are some holes in the mesh. The outside of the cube should be blue, the inside red.

You can use the <kbd>F</kbd> key in *Edit* mode to fill the holes. Use Edge Selection* (<kbd>2</kbd>) to select the edge.

For larger holes enable the "*Mesh: F2*" addon in *File > Preferences*. Then you can create a squad face when you just select 1 vertex in the corner. Make sure you are in *Vertex Selection* mode (<kbd>1</kbd>). Then confirm (left-click) or cancel (right-click/<kbd>Esc</kbd>) the drag mode after the new face is created. Doesn't matter what you click just don't accidentally move the newly created vertex.

[image: fill the holes animation]

**3. Overlapping Faces**

There is a large flipped red circle (N-gon) that covers the underlying mesh. I'm not sure if you need it (is it a cover with transparent material?). If you want to keep it, make sure it gets flipped (blue).

If you peek in there you will see that the walls of the round structure have 2 edge loops that overlap with the narrow outer edge of the sticking out rim. You need to fix/recreate these walls/edge loops. Then you can use (<kbd>Alt</kbd>)+(<kbd>N</kbd>), *Recalculate Outside* and Blender should be able to fix all the flipped faces.

[image: overlapping edge loops]

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot visually seeing it. And I couldn't figure out how to fix the holes I created by accident, so I went back to a previous backup model. Luckily I duplicate each stage and hide it in case I need to go back I won't have to start from the beginning.