# permanently joining objects forever

Tags: modeling

I'm a month new to this, and my first model I made a Rubik cube. When I made an edge piece, I made it from 3 separate objects and joined them together to make one piece. It worked for what I wanted in the end but if in the future I had joined the whole Rubik cube together for another blend file so all the pieces would just be once whole object and if I wanted to scramble the cube some more I would separate it by loose pieces. When I separated it, then all 12 edge pieces would also split up into 3 pieces separately also. So, as you can see in the image, I have selected an extruded circle. I have to remake the cube and I have already made 5 magnets (the extruded circles) so I'm wondering if I can just make one and duplicate it and permanently join it to the objects I make, so they won't ever separate even if I tried to separate by loose parts in the future.

[image]

Comment: from what I understand you just need to enable Auto-Merge and Snap option in order to merge the vertices? Also a question: your mesh is rather high-poly, do you need to 3D print or is it just for images? In the latter case, you can simplify your topology a lot

Comment: I had a hard time getting the loop tool to make a perfect circle, so I had to subdivide it once by 10 and one more time just by 1. Then ill go back and dissolve all the faces. I'm only a month into making anything with 3d, so I'm really trying to learn, but I know I'm taking the long way to make my ideas

Comment: It's not for printing, I just love Rubik cubes and want to make animations out of a 3d model.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need so many polygons if you can use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, in that case you can create circles with only 8 vertices. Also you don't need to subdivide your flat surfaces so much, example:

[image]

If the circle is on a quarter of the total face (you can even delete some edges):

[image]

Or:

[image]

From your topology:

[image]

Comment: Can it be done that way and have the circle off close in the corner because I think I saw something like this, but the example also showed the circle being in the center of the face too. And would the subdivide modifier mess with the rest of the object and interfere with the shape in any way like the bevels or extruded faces going inward.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it will help, it can even be more simplified, it depends on the whole object, try to work with as less polygons as possible

Comment: I just tried it and this is how mine turned out https://ibb.co/PGGmR68 sadly I'm not getting the same result, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I think I remember now why I didn't do it that way is because mine never turned out looking like yours when I say someone else doing it in a video

Comment: see my edit and try to clean your topology, you can use the knife tool, also dissolve edges with Ctrl X. Also, you don't need so many segments for your bevels (on the side of your object), particularly if you use a Subdivision Surface modifier. Maybe follow some tutorials on modeling?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating them after a proper joining will work. What I mean by a proper joining is that you have vertices between parts that have lined up at the same location and that you have merged those vertices do there are no duplicates. ["m" merge by distance] Without merging like that forever will you be able to separate them by pieces.
Now if you want to be able to separate parts in the future, I would use different materials in name, even if alike in every other way. That is a good way to have a way to break models apart quickly and easily.